# How do I fix the pen tool from jumping from its anchor in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, anchor-point

In Illustrator, for whatever reason, when I try and draw a straight line with the pen tool it jumps from where it is anchored.

It seems as though it's even on the same pixel, but it's not anchored in the same place.

When I do other angles it works fine (mostly). Align to Pixel Grid is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: re you drawing really small with snap on? I see Align to Pixel grid is *off* on the transform panel, but it is off for the document and new objects?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be caused by a snapping tool.

To fix:

Go to **View** and make sure that

- *Snap to Grid* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>)
- *Snap to point* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>)

Are toggled *off*

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

The fix is:

1. Under *Menu → Window → Transform,* uncheck *Align to Pixel Grid*.
2. Uncheck *Align New Objects to Pixel Grid* in the options for the *Transform* window.

That’s two spots to uncheck or it will keep doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my friend actually solved the problem and I will go ahead and write it up here to help anyone who is losing their mind as I was before. I am currently running Illustrator CC 2018, so I'm not sure where this is located on other versions.

But if one goes to the "Essentials Classic" workspace view (different than just "Essentials"), you will see an icon with a column of three boxes and an old school magnet. This button should NOT be depressed! Meaning that if it looks like this photo, you will have trouble, so unselect it!

[image: Essentials Classic panel]

Comment: That's Align to Pixel Grid for the document.